# Cant find the generated pdf off of my texmaker but can view it in preview

Tags: pdftex, texmaker

Every time I open my file in texmaker it shows this, instead of the right file path.
[image]

Building the file works fine, and even the preview works, but I cant find the output pdf anywhere! Even if I right click on the preview and select "Show in file browser" nothing happens.
Any idea what is wrong or how to fix it? I am on Ubuntu 19.10 if that helps.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe Texmaker does not have write permissions in the folder where your file is stored, so it saves the file and the pdf in some temporary virtual location. You could try saving your file in another folder with write permissions for every user to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: This seems to be a temp file. This usually happens when you start your editor, write a document and compile without saving it in your $HOME directory, e.g. under Documents. Save it under documents, then the pdf should end up in the same folder you've saved your file to.